# Expression Engine tags causing DIV to disappear!? How can I solve this?

Tags: html, css, tags, expressionengine

I am using Expression Engine to develop a site. I have created the page I want in a template file and now I am making use of EE's tags to make the content dynamic.

```
 {exp:channel:entries    channel="test123"} 
    {test123}
<div class="panel" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
   <div class="paneldiv" style="background-color: red;">
   hello there
   </div>
</div>
   {/test123}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The above code makes my DIV disappear. But if I remove the tags, the DIV shows up.

Its also worth noting that when the tags are in and I click "view rendered template" the DIV shows up.

Very strange! I've been bashing my head all day!

Comment: what kind of tag is: {test123}{/test123}.  What is the url you are using when the tags disappear?  What is the url you are getting when with "view rendered template"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the {test123} tag incorrectly.  First, I'm assuming that {test123} refers to a Channel Field within the 'test123' Channel.  If so, then you simply need to remove the {/test123} ending tag, as data field tags are usually single-variable tags.

The reason your div content is disappearing is that EE is failing to process {test123} as a variable pair, and therefore it doesn't show the content within.